# How do i connect my two modules?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, alu

I have to make a alu within a ralu that was 8 functions , but when I try to simulate the behavioral model for "ralu" all I get are X's (output) and Z's (input). What am I doing wrong? (When I simulate only the alu it works just fine)

```
module alu(
      input [3:0] op1,
      input [3:0] op2,
      input [2:0] func,
      output reg[3:0] out
    );
always@(*)
  case(func)
    3'b000: out=op1&op2; // functia AND
    3'b001: out=op1|op2; // OR
    3'b010: out=~(op1&op2);// NAND
    3'b011: out=~(op1|op2); //NOR
    3'b100: out=op1^op2; // XOR
    3'b101: out=op1~^op2; //XNOR
    3'b110: out=op1+op2;
    3'b111: out=op1-op2;
  endcase
endmodule

module ralu(
      input [3:0] in,
      input [2:0] func,
      input clk,
      input load,
      output [3:0] out
    );
reg [3:0] op1;
reg [3:0] op2;
always@(posedge clk)
  if(load) op2<=in;
  else op1<=in;
endmodule
```

Comment: Z's in the inputs means nothing is driving them. This can explain the X's. Your not showing how you are connecting the `alu` to the `ralu` or your test bench, so it is hard to diagnose.

Comment: my problem is actually that i don't know how to connect the two of them

Comment: You should try [googling](https://www.google.com/#q=verilog%20instance%20module) or read a Language Reference Manual (LRM) such as SystemVerilog [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) § 23. _Modules and hierarchy_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing declaration of `alu` in `ralu`, i.e.:

```
alu myALU(
    .op1(op1),
    .op2(op2),
    .func(func),
    .out(out)
);
```

Comment: i pretty sure this is a dumb question, but where exactly should i add this?

Comment: Or `alu myALU( .* );` since `@(*)` demonstrates that at least Verilog 2001 is supported.

Comment: @user3629371: inside your `ralu` module definition.